# FormControl is not updated with setValue

Tags: angular, typescript

My input field that holds `unitCost` is not updated as with `patchValue` method.

```
  onTreatmentSelected(event: Event, index: number) {
    const selectedTreatmentId = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement)?.value;
    if (selectedTreatmentId) {
      const selectedTreatment = this.treatments.find(treatment => treatment.id === Number(selectedTreatmentId));
      if (selectedTreatment) {
        const items = this.itemsFormArray;
        const selectedItem = items.at(index) as FormGroup;
        if (selectedItem.controls['unitCost'] !== null) {
          selectedItem.patchValue({ unitCost: selectedTreatment.price });
          console.log(selectedItem);
        }
        this.updateTreatment(selectedTreatmentId, selectedItem);
      }
    }
  }
```

```
 <tbody *ngIf="invoiceForm">
   <tr class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let item of itemsFormArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
       <td style="width: 20px">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
       <td class="col-sm-9">
         <select class="form-control" formControlName="item (change)="onTreatmentSelected($event, i)">
            <option *ngFor="let treatment of treatments" [value]="treatment.id">{{ treatment.id}}</option>
         </select>
       </td>                                                    
       <td><input id="unitCost" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="unitCost"></td>
       <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" (click)="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
       <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-danger font-18" title="Remove" (click)="removeRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "formArrayName"

```
 <form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">

      <!--see the formArrayName-->
      <div formArrayName="treatments">

        <div *ngFor="let group of itemsFormArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
           <select formControlName="item" (change)="onTreatmentSelected($event, i)">
              <option *ngFor="let treatment of treatments" [value]="treatment.id">{{ treatment.id}}</option>
           </select>
           <input formControlName="unitCost">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

NOTE: You can simplify your code using some like

```
  onTreatmentSelected(el:any,index:number)
  {
    const treatment=this.treatments.find((x:any)=>x.id==el.target.value)
    if (treatment)
      this.itemsFormArray.at(index).patchValue({unitCost:treatment.price})
  }
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6nrygw?file=src%2Fmain.ts)